# Nodejs Sharp webp lossless compression

Tags: node.js, sharp

I'm developing a similar service of Imgix and I'm using Sharp.

But the webp lossless compression Imgix get better results than Sharp. The same image with the same width and height in Imgix have 453 KB and with Sharp 1.3 MB.

Some recommendation to increase compression without losing quality?

The code that I'm using:

```
https.get(url, function (response) {
    let transform = sharp().toFormat('webp').resize(width, height);
    return response.pipe(transform).webp({lossless:true}).pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Can you share two file compress with Imgix & Sharp on your question?

Comment: https://ic.imgix.net/1/5c473f5253098?format=webp&lossless=1 IMGIX lossless: 138kb 

The same image with Sharp webp lossless have 436kb

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see that [document](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/api-output/#webp) have some fileds in options: quality, alphaQuality, nearLossless, force. Can you try it? And compare with IMGIX

> - **quality**: Number quality, integer 1-100 (optional, default 80)
> - **alphaQuality**: Number quality of alpha layer, integer 0-100 (optional,    default 100)
> - **lossless**: Boolean use lossless compression mode    (optional, default false)
> - **nearLossless**: Boolean use near_lossless    compression mode (optional, default false)
> - **force**: Boolean force WebP    output, otherwise attempt to use input format (optional, default    true)

```
https.get(url, function (response) {
    let transform = sharp().toFormat('webp').resize(width, height);
    return response.pipe(transform).webp({lossless:true, quality: 60, alphaQuality: 80, force: false}).pipe(res);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Documentation on how to use Sharp's [webp output options](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-output#webp) is non-existent AFAICT, but according to this [comment](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/pull/685#discussion_r96575792) the options `nearLossless` and `quality` should be used together, while the `lossless:true` option is equivalent to `nearLossless:true,quality:100`

In my experience, `nearLossless:true,quality:50` will cut the file size to less than half of `lossless:true`, while retaining most of the quality.

Comment: Note that `nearLossless` is disabled for [small images](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebp/blob/1fb9f3dcf18b2aff35dcb7a8f6fa4a6c756efb75/src/enc/near_lossless_enc.c#L125) below 64x64px.